Add metadata to stripe Subscription.resume in python SDK
I have made a bunch of endpoints for subscriptions like modify, cancel, and create Customer.create, all of these take a metadata parameter, that will be available in the hook event, except when i use stripe.Customer.resume i get an error saying
Received unknown parameter: metadata
Here's a simplified version of my code:
@routes.post("/company_management/resume-subscription")
async def resume_subscription(request):
    try:
        data = await request.json()
        subscription_id = data.get("subscription_id")
        user = await get_user(request)
        if not user:
            return web.json_response({"error": "Not found"}, status=404)
        
        
        # update the user status
        async with request.app["db"].acquire() as conn:
            async with conn.cursor(aiomysql.DictCursor) as cur:
                user_id = user.get("user_id")
                
                await stripe.Subscription.resume(
                subscription_id,
                billing_cycle_anchor='unchanged',
                metadata={"user_id": user_id}
                )
                
        return web.json_response({"message": "Subscription resumed successfully", "status": "success"})
    except Exception as e:
        return web.json_response({"error": str(e)}, status=400)

I know I could resume a subscription using the Subscription.Modify like:
 await stripe.Subscription.modify(
    subscription_id,
    pause_collection='',
    metadata={"user_id": user_id}
)

I want to keep this as a last resort, and use the Resume method because it may trigger the Subscription.resumed webhook.
some extra questions, the modify method, if used to pause a subscription it only triggers the Subscription.updated webhook, how to trigger the Subscription.paused?


stripe.Customer.create

You meant stripe.Subscription.resume?
If so, the Resume Subscription endpoint doesn't take all the properties of a Subscription as parameters, which is why you can't update fields like metadata with it. If you want to resume the Subscription and modify it in the same call you should use:
await stripe.Subscription.modify(
    subscription_id,
    pause_collection='',
    metadata={"user_id": user_id}
)


umm yes resume not create, modify already works, but it doesn't trigger the resume hook, instead both pause and resume trigger the same Subscription.updated, I am currently using modify for both, and i've handled it in code, but in the future if i get another method that triggers Subscription.updated it'll surly break.

What would break exactly?

when I receive a Subscription.updated event, there's no way to know what was modified, so I have to assume that if pause_collection attribute was '' then the event was caused by a resume if it was not '' then it must've been active then paused, if a third action triggered the event, then i am gonna do the same check on the pause_collection and assume that it was either paused or resumed.

this seems like a gray area in the Stripe flow

"when I receive a Subscription.updated event, there's no way to know what was modified" ->  the previous_attributes field indicates what has changed. https://docs.stripe.com/api/events/object#event_object-data-previous_attributes

@karllekko ok wow, this is very helpful, Thanks a lot.
